# How to print names of objects from a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
RED = '\u001b[31m'
BLACK = '\u001b[30m'
effects = [RED, BLACK]
print(effects)
```

current output =>

```
['\x1b[31m', '\x1b[30m']
```

how to get the following output without importing additional libraries? =>

```
['RED', 'BLACK']
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to define a dictionary instead?

Comment: You cannot print variable names, at least not in a straight forward non-messy way. Make your `effects` a dictionary and print the keys instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a couple of dictionaires called something like `COLOR_TO_ANSI_ESCAPE_CODE` and `ANSI_ESCAPE_CODE_TO_COLOR` if you don't want to import any external libraries:

```
COLOR_TO_ANSI_ESCAPE_CODE = {
    'Black': '\u001b[30m',
    'Red': '\u001b[31m',
    'Green': '\u001b[32m',
    'Yellow': '\u001b[33m',
    'Blue': '\u001b[34m',
    'Magenta': '\u001b[35m',
    'Cyan': '\u001b[36m',
    'White': '\u001b[37m',
    'Reset': '\u001b[0m',
}

ANSI_ESCAPE_CODE_TO_COLOR = {
    '\x1b[30m': 'Black',
    '\x1b[31m': 'Red',
    '\x1b[32m': 'Green',
    '\x1b[33m': 'Yellow',
    '\x1b[34m': 'Blue',
    '\x1b[35m': 'Magenta',
    '\x1b[36m': 'Cyan',
    '\x1b[37m': 'White',
    '\x1b[0m': 'Reset',
}

RED = '\u001b[31m'
BLACK = '\u001b[30m'
effects = [RED, BLACK]
print(effects)
effect_names = [ANSI_ESCAPE_CODE_TO_COLOR[code] for code in effects]
print(effect_names)
```

**Output:**

```
['\x1b[31m', '\x1b[30m']
['Red', 'Black']
```